# Fourier expansion of Eisenstein series

Tags: modular-forms

In the Fourier expansion of the Eisenstein series (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Fourier_series)), we see that there is the term 
$$ \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} q^n.$$ 
Wikipedia claims that the expansion holds for any $|q| \le 1$. In Serre's book named a course in arithmetic, he defined $q := e^{2\pi iz}$ which has modulus $1$. But for this geometric series to converge, don't we need $|q| < 1$?

Comment: $q$ does not have modulus 1 as $z$ is in the upper half-plane.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense! Do you mind writing this as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: The Wikipedia claim is correct **if** $|q|<1$ since if $q=1$ the infinite sum diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$ |q| = \exp(-2\pi \Im(z)),$$
with $\Im(z) > 0$ so $|q| < 1$.